# Updating IPython

Tags: ipython, jupyter-notebook

After updating to master (3.0) via python setupegg.py develop I'm getting the below error when trying to start Ipython notebook I did try the git submodule update

```
File "/home/tom/ipython/IPython/nbformat/validator.py", line 5, in <module>
from jsonschema import SchemaError
ImportError: No module named jsonschema
```

Not sure where I messed up

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you did not mess up, current master of ipython requires jsonschema and jsonpointer used for the validation of saved ipython notebooks.
you can usually install them with your packagemanager of choice (e.g. pip or apt-get).
The debian/ubuntu packages are `python-jsonschema` and `python-json-pointer`.

the current latest stable release (2.1.0) does not require these modules.

Comment: Thanks!Just a note took a few seconds to find json-pointer instead of jsonpointer

Comment: thanks, edited, didn't know myself jsonpointer was packaged because I also searched for it without the hypen